# Swift class with only class methods and a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I want a class with all class methods.  I would like to use a delegate so my view controllers (conforming to the protocol)  can call `AlertFactory.passwordResetSucess()` and display the alert.

1. Is there a way to make this this work?  A way to use the delegate from this class?
2. Is this bad practice?  Bad form?  Why?
3. What's a good way to make this happen?  There will be other class methods used in several views.

Thanks!

```
    protocol AlertFactoryDelegate 
    {
        func showAlert(alert: UIAlertController)
    }

    class AlertFactory: NSObject {

     let delegate: AlertFactoryDelegate!

     class func passwordResetSuccess() 
     {
         var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Yay", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
         delegate.showAlert(alert)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `delegate` to be `static`, and access it with `AlertFactory.delegate`

```
class AlertFactory: NSObject {
    static weak var delegate: AlertFactoryDelegate?

    class func passwordResetSuccess() {
        ...
        self.delegate?.showAlert(alert)
    }
}
```

To create a delegate:

```
class SomeClass: AlertFactoryDelegate {
    ... // Implement everything the protocol requires
}

// Asssing a delegate
AlertFactory.delegate = SomeClass()
```

Comment: That is correct behevior. You must first set the delegate to something before expecting anything to happen

Comment: I suppose this is where I'm stumped ... I can't set it = AlertFactoryDelegate() because protocols don't have constructors ... how do I initialize it and where?

Comment: You'll want to create a class that implements the protocol, then assign an instance of that class as the delegate. (This is how UITableViewDelegate and such work) (see the last code block in my answer)

Comment: Ok!  That's what I was missing!  Thank you.  My plan was to implement this protocol from multiple view controllers.  Does that make sense, changing the delegate as I bounce from view to view?

Comment: You could either change the delegate, or pass the delegate to each view controller through the segue

Comment: So that's not bad form then?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: in above code, delegate is the strong var which will create a retain cycle. class object assigned to AlertFactory.delegate will never be deallocated.

Comment: Extremely unlikely you'd ever want to do this. If you do want to do this you should use the system notifications instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use the `SINGLETON` command pattern, its a very common practice. You should read up on it, but basically means there is only 1 ever instance of it and you can call methods off of it when needed (or send things to it as needed). Common examples are EventSystem objects or GlobalObserver objects, Factories, and ContextManagers.

Here is information on it:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

2. Using a SINGLETON has tradeoffs, but can be very useful in many situations. This seems like a good pattern for your problem.
3. You need to initialize your `delegate` when your app starts. From then on, when another view controller needs to set that delegate you can assign it: (this assumes you made delegate public and its a SINGLETON)

`_myViewController.actionThatRequiresDelegate = AlertFactory.delegate`

As mentioned in one of the other answers, using Swifts trailing syntax closure system is a great way to use anonymous functions and you could do your logic in there, or communicate with your delegate in there.

***update***

Initialize in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
override init()
{
    AlertFactory.init()
}
```

Then in your AlertFactory

```
public static AlertFactoryDelegate myDelegate

public static func init()
{
    myDelegate = new AlertFactoryDelegate()
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use a singleton but I still can't figure out how to initialize the delegate ...

Comment: Well a basic way would be to open the AppDelegate file and initialize it there.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work.  Even with the correct Swift syntax (above is incorrect) when I try to initialize the delegate in the init() is says that the class doesn't have a member with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an instance variable on a class without instantiating the class first.  Is there a reason you don't want to instantiate the class, and just want to use class methods instead?  If you feel that you have good reason to use class methods over instance methods, then you have two potential options:

1. Pass a delegate as a parameter to the class method.
2. Use Completion Blocks instead of Delegation.  [Here's a decent example in swift.](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/)

In my personal experience I find blocks to be preferable.

**EDIT:** I haven't used Swift that much lately, but as @Skrundz pointed out you can indeed use a static variable on a class in Swift.